# Matlab list comprehension

Tags: matlab, list-comprehension

Can I write the following in a one liner?

```
x = [1,3,5,7,9]
res = zeros(1,size(x,2));
for i=1:size(x,2);
    res(i) = foo(x(i));
end;
```

Assume that the foo function does not handle arrays as expected. In my case foo returns a scalar even when giving an array as argument.

In Python, for instance, it would look like this:

```
x = [1,3,5,7,9]
res = [foo(y) for y in x]
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[`arrayfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/arrayfun.html) is what you need. For example:

```
res = arrayfun(@foo, x)
```

Since `foo` always returns a scalar, the above will work and `res` will also be a vector of the same dimensions as `x`. If `foo` returns variable length output, then you will have to set `'UniformOutput'` to `false` or `0` in the call to `arrayfun`. The output will then be a `cell` array.

Comment: @LucyBrennan It creates a [function handle](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/brfpxgt-1.html). You can read that doc page and the related links for more info

Comment: Thx. What if foo actually takes two arguments, and I want to keep the second argument the constant over all iterations?

Comment: @LucyBrennan You can define what arguments the [anonymous function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f4-70115.html) takes. For example `arrayfun(@(y)foo(y,2),x)` supplies the list `x` as arguments to the anonymous function where ever `y` appears. The second argument is a constant `2`. You can read the linked document for more

Answer (score 7):

Just to add to the good answer of @yoda, instead of using `UniformOutput`, you can also use `{}` brackets:

```
res = arrayfun(@(t){foo(t)}, x)
```

Also, in some occasions, `foo` is already vectorized.

```
x = 1:10;
foo = @(t)(power(t,2));
res = foo(x);
```

Comment: could u explain in a little more detail what `foo = @(t)(power(t,2));` means?

Comment: the issue is what if I want to do something like `{i^2 for i to N}`? But I dont want to define a function for `^2`, is there an alternative?